# How select the correct node in a SQL binary tree?

Tags: php, sql

I am building a simple web page with a 20 questions style game. The first question is presented and the user answers yes or no get to the next question. I am unsure on how to point to the next required node with my query.

I have radio buttons for selecting the answer and a submit button. I presume I need to hand over something with the radio buttons with `$_GET`, but I am really struggling. I am assuming that I need a way to know which node the user is on to the find the correct answer node.

```
<form action="play.php" method="GET">
    <input type="submit" name="start" value="start game">
</form>
<?php
$query="SELECT `message`, `parentID`,`answerYesID`, `answerNoID`, `nodeID` FROM `creature`";
$where="";
$current=1;
function output($query, $where, $dbconn) {
    $result=mysqli_query($dbconn, $query.$where);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo("<tr><td>{$row['message']}</td></tr><br>");
        echo "</table>";
    }
}

echo '<form action="play.php" method="GET">
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value ="`answerYesID`">yes
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="`answerNoID`">no
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>';
if(isset($_GET['start'])) {
    $where="WHERE `parentID` is NULL";
    output($query, $where, $dbconn);
}
if(isset($_GET['submit']) && $_GET['answer'] == "answerYesID") {
    $where="WHERE `nodeID` = ".$_GET['answer'];
    output($query, $where, $dbconn);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give a Question ID to each question and get data according to this Question ID

Make ID column an **auto_increment**
get the id using **GET** method and the for next button just increment by one

```
$next=$_GET['id']+1;
```

and make sure that this number doesn't exceed 20(number of Question)

```
$next%=20;
```

now action atribute for for would be

```
action="play.php?id=<?php echo $next;?>"
```

Comment: Many thanks for helping, really appreciate it. I have a nodeID for each row in the table which is auto_increment. but the number of the next node may not be just the next number up from the nodeID, it could be the ID from any node in the table depending on where the answer is

Comment: you can get next valid nodeid from database